# Detect window.close() function on a window using an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two views, lets call them view1 and view2.

view1 is the main view, and view2 just has a script inside it that calls window.close() inside of it.

view1 uses the window.open(url) function to open new window with a url.

inside that window, after I click on a button, it calls the method inside the controller that return a new view called(view2).
as I said, view2 simply has the window.close() function so it closes and focus goes back to view1 window.

the questions is:
is it possible to have an event that detects when the window.close() function has been used, or an even that detects the window getting closed not by the user?

a rough diagram of it:

[image]

this is the function that opens the new window, stores him inside a variable and then trying to attache an event to that window.

that event will evoke the GetInstagramPictures inside of it.

```
function AuthenticateInstagramAPI(){

    var win = window.open("https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=346912513373650&redirect_uri=https://localhost:49000/Actions/AccessTokenAuth&scope=user_media,user_profile&response_type=code")
   
    win.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        GetInstagramPictures;
    });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `beforeunload` or `unload` events?

Comment: yeah...they dont seem to work unless a user is doing the action

Comment: I have added a code snippet of the event

Comment: You need parentheses after `GetInstagramPictures` if you want to invoke the function.

Comment: added them, still the same result

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not but `win.closed` is true when it is open and false when closed. If beforeunload not working doubt there is any other event that will. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @charlietfl even if the close is invoked from a different tab?

Comment: ugh doesn't matter, I still need this event to fire off whenever the view is closed so it can invoke the function

Comment: Most events are only triggered from user actions. The general philosophy is if code is performing the action, it can call the other functions that need to be run directly.

Comment: Yes....for example I have an app that uses another window for Oauth. When I open it I run a timer to check `closed` from main page. It gets closed by script in that window calling window.close(). This might be what you are doing to do is it?

Comment: what happens if the timer runs out? window is closed and user has to re open it? because that's exactly what im doing, its an oath window and I need to fire a function when he authenticates, @charlietfl

Comment: Ok...in page that opens it I start setInterval. User authorizes and token comes back to an html page that  uses postMessage to pass token to main page and calls window.close. The setInterval stops when the `win.closed` is true, either by user not authorizing and manually closing or the window.close() call

Comment: Has been a long time since I looked at that code. I'm pretty sure that's everything involved in  how it works

Comment: and don't forget to clearInterval()

Comment: I think I spent a whole day trying other libraries and testing all that.... turned out to be simpler than I expected once I got the right idea

Comment: exactly what I was going thru.. lol, beeing trying to break my head all day thinking about ways to do that, had no idea about window.closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the new window start a `setInterval()` to keep checking `win.closed` every few seconds or whatever you feel appropriate.

It will be true if user closes window manually or if you call `window.close()` in the remote window.

When it is true....stop the interval timer with `clearInterval()`